# MySQL/C# Insert Issue

Tags: c#, mysql

Not sure what is wrong with this

```
//Setup MySQL
    private MySqlConnection datconnection = new MySqlConnection();
    //private MySqlDataAdapter datdata = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    DataGrid datgridInfo = new DataGrid();
    int connect;
    private Form_NewEnquiry frm_parent;

    public Form_AddVenue(Form_NewEnquiry frm1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm_parent = frm1;
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connect = 0;
        try
        {
                datconnection.ConnectionString =
                "server=127.0.0.1;"
                + "database=as;"
                + "uid=a;"
                + "password=a;";
                connect = 1;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Unavailable");
        }


        //INSERT SQL Code to Insert Venue
        if (connect == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                datconnection.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO venues (venue_name,venue_address1,venue_address2,venue_town,venue_county,venue_postcode,venue_telephone,venue_fax,venue_email,venue_web,venue_maxguests) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", datconnection);
                command.Parameters.Add("name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45, tbName.Text.ToString());
                command.Parameters.Add("address1", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45, tbAddress1.Text.ToString());
                command.Parameters.Add("address2", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45, tbAddress2.Text.ToString());
                command.Parameters.Add("town", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45, tbTown.Text.ToString());
                command.Parameters.Add("county", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45, tbCounty.Text.ToString());
                command.Parameters.Add("postcode", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 10, tbPostcode.Text.ToString());
                command.Parameters.Add("telephone", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 15, tbTelephone.Text.ToString());
                command.Parameters.Add("fax", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 15, tbFax.Text.ToString());
                command.Parameters.Add("email", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 255, tbEmail.Text.ToString());
                command.Parameters.Add("web", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 255, tbWeb.Text.ToString());
                command.Parameters.Add("maxguests", MySqlDbType.Int32, 11, nudNoOfGuests.Value.ToString());
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //datdata.InsertCommand = command;
            }
            catch (Exception eea)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error storing data");
                MessageBox.Show(eea.ToString());
                connect = 0;
            }
            finally
            {
                datconnection.Close();
            }
        }
        if (connect == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");

            //Print

            //Close Window
            frm_parent.reloadVenue();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

This gives me the error System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Comment: what line is throwing the exception?

Comment: At the `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: I have fixed this by just coding the SQL string without command.Parameters.Add (instead the SQL string has the values concatenated. I know there is a risk of SQL Injection by doing so, however this is only a small internal system.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the size of some of the data is more than the size of the parameter you have specified. for example

```
command.Parameters.Add("name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45, tbName.Text);
```

is the size of the tbName.Text string less than 45. what about using

```
command.Parameters.Add("name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, tbName.Text.Length, tbName.Text);
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for this - however when changing the same error is thrown. I have used the static lengths here as these are the MySQL length, therefore throwing a proper exception when the values are longer than MySQL will accept.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the **ToString()** on the Text property it already is a string please avoid it.

Also

```
command.Parameters.Add("maxguests", MySqlDbType.Int32, 11, nudNoOfGuests.Value.ToString())
```

This is expecting a int parameter and you are passing in a string, please use **Convert.ToInt32** to pass in the value.

Normally these errors occur due to difference in the number of parameters declared and passed to the command but seems fine in your case. What type of control is **nudNoOfGuests** maybe that is causing the format error

Comment: Hey,Thanks for your help - however the .Value.ToString() has to be there as Parameters.Add always expects the 4th parameter to be a String.

Changing this to `command.Parameters.Add("maxguests", MySqlDbType.Int32, 11, 10);` throws an "Argument 4 cannot convert from int to string"

I do agree, however, that the ToString() isn't needed on a Text property - force of habbit

Comment: So nudNoOfGuests is returning a valid value ?

Comment: Yes - However even with hard coding a string of an integer in this fails

Comment: Can you try the same by changing the params as ?name,?address1,?address2 ... so on